# How can I query an FS collection in Meteor from the command line?

Tags: mongodb, image, meteor, collectionfs, database

It is very useful to run `meteor mongo` and query collections from the command line, for debugging purposes, etc.

Recently, I have added the `collectionFS` package to enable image storage in the database. However, I am unable to query the database from the command line.

`db.fs.collection_name.find()` is not doing the trick, and I can't seem to find the correct command anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Meteor Mongo console: `meteor mongo`

See all the collections that are available: `show collections`

Look for the one that has `cfs.collection_name.files`

Choose the one that has your collection name. For example, I'm using collectionFS with gridFS for images. When I type `show collections`, I see `cfs_gridfs.images.files` so I just do: `db.cfs_gridfs.images.files.find()` to see those files.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you find it difficult to use the command line or terminal, you have a UI for `MongoDB` called [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/download.html) which is easy to install and use. I use Meteor with its default port number and then in Robomongo it is used as `3001`.

And the query to view collection here is same as `db.collection_name.find()`.